# Understanding fiber bundles over manifolds of finite type (finite good cover)

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

I am reading Bott-Tu "Differential forms in Algebraic Topology" and trying to understand proof of Leray-Hirsch. During the process I realized that I do not understand basic definitions.

Let $M$ be smooth $n$-dimensional manifold of finite type (admits fintie good cover). Let $\pi:E\to M$ be a fiber bundle over $M$ with fiber $M$. My question is: does this imply that I can get the "bundle structure" from homomorphisms that would go $$\phi_\alpha:E|_{U_\alpha}\xrightarrow{\simeq}U_\alpha\times F$$ with $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha=1}^k$ being the given good cover?

I would say that the answer is no, because it is just a cover, not a chart, doesn't come with diffeomorphisms onto $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I feel that I think about something very wrong, so if someone can help me realize what it would be really great. Here are my thoughts:

What does the good cover give me? Let's say $M$ can be covered by a good cover $\{U,V\}$. I know that it means that the intersection $U\cap V$ is contractible, i.e. diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. How do I connect it with the fiber bundle? Does it actually induce a smooth structure for $M$? Just by inclusions? But this would imply that all elements of a good cover have to be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: How are you defining a good cover? As far as I'm aware, they are typically defined such that *all* nonempty finite intersections are contractible. In particular, all $U_\alpha$ are contractible, and thus $\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ are trivial.

Comment: @Kajelad Yes, I have the same definition, and I guess I missed the detail "all" meaning if I take $U_\alpha\cap U_\alpha$ it has to be contractible? Yeah I see it now, thank you for the comment!